# Why is my microphone's input a constant low air sound?

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, microphone

[image]

It does the same behavior with all of my computers (Windows 8.1, 10 and 11)

### My main computer:

- Windows 11 Pro (latest version).
- All drivers have been installed by Windows Update
- Microphone Access is turned on.
- Realtek High Definition Audio Driver (6.0.1.7548).
- Custom built, with an HP 18E4 motherboard.
- When connected to the black socket with a headset and a microphone sign:

  [image]
- When connected to the cyan audio socket:

  [image]
- When connected to a USB sound card:

  [image]

Comment: What type of mic, what type of plug? Picture might help. Does the socket have a specific colour surround, or any type of marking?

Comment: What happens when / if you enable the second Audio input in your screen shot.

Comment: @John, It is enabled and not plugged in

Comment: OK, mic is wired like a headset, laptop-style. Still need to see the socket. If it's part of the old style 3 colours, blue, green, pink it may not recognise that pin-out, only that something has been inserted in the socket.

Comment: Well, the socket looks like it's capable of taking a headset, so I see no physical reason it wouldn't work, assuming the pinout agrees with the logo [no reason it shouldn't on a pre-built machine, only if you built it yourself] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awjry.png What you're left with is that your mic might be OMTP & your computer CTIA, in which case you'd need an adapter to swap the standards [same plug, different wiring] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCWhP.png See if you can find documentation on the pinouts of each.

Comment: What is the exact make and model of the PC you are having these issues with? Posting a [huge picture of the case](https://superuser.com/revisions/1732316/5) is utterly useless. What matters is the make and model.

Comment: First, the picture of the case is for something else, Second, this is a built PC, so you want the whole specs or sound card only? Or something else?

Comment: how about the motherboard and chassis

Comment: @AZeed “First, the picture of the case is for something else…” What else? Unless it has anything to do with this specific question then the image does not help. I mean it is an HP case as [seen here](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/618pN99P-rL._AC_SL1144_.jpg). I see a microphone jack and headphone jack on the front of the case. But then again I have no idea what you mean by, “…this is a built PC…” Do you mean pre-built? Or factory built? It sure as hell is not a custom built PC. Anyway, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1732352/167207) is the correct answer.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, It is a custom built PC

Comment: >> headphone's microphone worked fine!  Great!  What model headphone?  What port(s) worked?

Comment: @BlindSpots, [This is the headphone I got](https://www.amazon.eg/-/en/S602-Virtual-Surround-Headphone-Microphone/dp/B09232RVMD).

Comment: Thanks @AZeed, please accept my answer as the headset you bought uses USB or 2 x TRS cable per the PC99 standard see image:  https://imgur.com/a/BPZc735

Comment: Sure, but please change all TRSS to TRRS first

Comment: Okay, I corrected the 2 typos in the answer.

Comment: AZeed - you keep editing this to push it back to the top of the queue, but we're still missing vital information - what the pinout of each device actually is. Without that, no-one can answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin, It is already answered, I just edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TRRS jack in TRS Port

You are using a TRRS jack  (as in the picture you provided) in a TRS audio port.  The audio ports on your HP 18E4 motherboard are TRS, including the dual use port (headphone "or" mic, not both). When you insert a TRS jack in a HP dual use port, the PC's audio software should prompt you to identify whether you've just connected a mic or headphones, and configure itself accordingly.

While it is physically possible to use a TRRS jack in a TRS port while retaining the audio out (speaker), the microphone signal would be lost which is your experience.

### Your Mic Jack is TRRS

Most modern mobile device jacks need to support headsets with stereo audio, a microphone, and often signaling (play, pause, mute).  For this reason they use TRRS so that there are enough wires for all the signals that need to be passed.  Most smartphones now use the TRRS CTIA standard. Your Mic is intended for these devices.  You can tell by the number of rings and also the image you shared notes that it is "Compatible with iPhone, iPad..." etc. Since your Lavalier mic is only a mic (does not have headphones integrated), the rings that would normally pass incoming left and right audio signals in a headset will be dummies (not in use)  and only included for compatibility with the TRRS port that they it would normally be plugged into.

If you see PC System Design Guide (PC-99) color-coding on the audio ports on the PC (pink, lime green etc.) that will provide additional confirmation.

**PC System Design Guide** ([Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_System_Design_Guide)
Hardware design requirements and recommendations (Microsoft and Intel 1997–2001).

**PC-99 Color-Coding** ([Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_System_Design_Guide#Color-coding_scheme_for_connectors_and_ports))

**Pink:** 701C Mic - 3.5 mm TRS

**Light Blue** 284C Line In - 3.5 mm TRS

**Lime Green:** 577C Line Out - 3.5 mm TRS

### The Fix

You need to convert your TRRS jack to a TRS jack using an adapter/splitter.  These are very common and cost about $5.

If you search your favorite retailer for "TRRS Female to Dual TRS Male Adapter" you will find one for a few dollars.

[image: TRRS Female to Dual TRS Male Adapter]

**NB:** I don't use a Lavalier so don't know if there is any signaling built in. I don't see any evidence in the picture but be aware that, if so,  those features would not be supported.

Comment: Case design says it's going to already be a TRRS. Current bet is CTIA/OMTP conflict.

Comment: Your odds don't look good :-)

Comment: Is TRRS = CTIA (Microphone) and TRS = OMTP (Motherboard)?

Comment: We don't know - you have to look up the spec for each.

Comment: Is it TRSS or TRRS?

Comment: @AZeed TRS does not = OMTP. TRRS has two standards: CTIA 'OR' OMTP . CTIA is the prevailing standard adopted by the mobile industry. Your Lavalier mic TRRS cable is states on the box image that it is compatible with Apple which MEANS it is CTIA as that is the standard they adopted

Comment: @AZeed T=tip R=ring S=sleeve